# Не работает register_next_step_handler в классах, python+pyTelegramBotAPI(telebot)

Tags: python, telebot

Товарищи, такая проблема, решил переписать своего бота с использованием классов. Получилось так, что register_next_step_handler перестал работать находясь внутри классов.
Прим. кода:

```
from another_module import SomeClass2

class SomeClass:
    @staticmethod
    def func1(message): # вызывается из другого модуля посредством register_next_step_handler
        arg1 = message.text
        send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Send me arg2")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(send, lambda m: SomeClass.func2(m, arg1))

    @staticmethod
    def func2(message, arg1):
        arg2 = message.text
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Alright, now i have 2 args")
        SomeClass2.some_func(arg1, arg2)
```

Вне классов такая конструкция была жизнеспособна, но будучи внутри класса, не происходит вызова func2 при отправке сообщения боту.
Ожидалось, что будет произведена передача arg1 из другого модуля, и далее накопление аргументов и передача их куда-либо.